Coverage is not collected for symlinked directory
I've symlinked a directory into my app's folder (apps/evergreen, see below), and I've configured jest to search for test files in that directory, and also to collect coverage from that folder.
Testing seems to work fine, as all tests pass successfully. However, when I set collectCoverage: true, no coverage is collected:
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================

Here is the file structure:
root
├── apps
│   ├── evergreen
│   │   ├── .tmp
|   │   │   ├── shared  <--- this is a symlink to "apps/shared"
│   │   ├── jest
│   │   │   ├── config.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.jest.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.webpack.json
├── shared
│   ├── components
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tsconfig.webpack.json


Here is Jest config.js in apps/evergreen:
{
  rootDir: "../",
  roots: ["<rootDir>/.tmp/shared"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testMatch: ["**/*.test.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/", "/tests/"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        tsconfig: "./tsconfig.jest.json",
        babelConfig: "./babel.config.js",
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": ["babel-jest", { configFile: "./babel.config.js" }],
    "^.+.scss$":
      "<rootDir>/../../config/jest/transformers/css-modules-transform.js",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^(assets|config|shared)/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../../$1/$2",
  },
  coverageReporters: ["text-summary", "lcov", "json"],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage",
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "<rootDir>/.tmp/shared/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "!<rootDir>/.tmp/shared/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/coverage/",
    "/dist/",
    "/__snapshots__/",
    "/__mocks__/",
  ],
};


Any ideas why this might happening? Does Jest, for some reason, not collect coverage from files in a symlink directory?
